# Is the following set a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $ G=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & a\\
        a & a\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ where $a\in \Bbb R, a \neq0$. I need to show that $G$ is a group under matrix multiplication. The problem is determinant of the matrix is $0$, and if I am to find the inverse and conclude that the inverse is within the set, I come to divide by $0$. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: @WillJagy Actually, this is from the book and the book says it is group even if determinant is $0$

Comment: You should start by finding the identity element.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is the identity $\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}$ identity element here?

Comment: @WillJagy Gallian, 8th edition, page 58, problem 52

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton Well, what happens if you square that element?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I get $\begin{pmatrix}
        2ka^k & 2ka^k\\
        2ka^k & 2ka^k\\
        \end{pmatrix}$ if I keep multiplying it by itself?

Comment: I have no idea how you got a $k$ there, or why you changed your earlier comment to become the $0$-matrix which by definition is not in the set.

Comment: @WillJagy It does happen to be a group (if I am not mistaken, it is the maximal subgroup generated by the idempotent that the OP has yet to find in the monoid of square $2\times 2$ matrices).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am seriously lost already.

Comment: Well, write up what happens when you multiply two matrices of this form and see what must be the case for the result to equal one of them.

Comment: As I interstand things there is no matrix  $B $ such that $AB= \begin {bmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &1 \end {bmatrix} $ because the determinant is zero however this doesn't matter because the identity is not the normal matrix identity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, clever question, given a subset of a group, we may get an identity element that need not be the original identity element. One of those "fixed ideas" that need loosening from time to time.

Comment: @WillJagy We need a semigroup for this (we can't do it inside a group). But there we indeed get a subgroup for each idempotent (for finite semigroups there is then a maximal one, but we probably need more assumptions for that in general).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the identity element is $$I = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$$ as the standard identity matrix does not even lie in $G$. Its quick to check for all $A \in G$, $AI = IA = A$. One can certainly find inverses with respect to this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The identity element is $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2 \end{array} \right)$. Group axioms verification is routine.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $\phi:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to G$ given by $\phi(a)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a/2&a/2\\a/2&a/2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is a bijection and that it's multiplicative, and you have right away that $G$ is a group isomorphic to the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers.

This is because $\phi(a)=\phi(1\cdot a)=\phi(1)\phi(a)=\phi(a)\phi(1)$ for all $a$ (yielding an identity) and $\phi(1)=\phi(aa^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(a^{-1})=\phi(a^{-1})\phi(a)$ demonstrating that everything has an inverse.